# Use sub2ind instead of loop for multidimensional arrays. Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I need to find a value of element which has maximum absolute value in a given dimension (in my case second dimension). For 2D matrix it is easy

```
A=normrnd(0,1,60,150);
[~,idx]=max(abs(A),[],2);
MAX=A(sub2ind(size(A), 1:size(A,1), idx'));
```

But with three dimensional situation I have a problem using `sub2ind()` function. **I understand that it is dummy question, but I really could not find a solution** *(may be because of Friday)*

The working code with for loop:

```
B=normrnd(0,1,60,150,450);
[~,idx]=max(abs(B),[],2);
MAX=nan(size(B,1),size(B,3));
for iDim1=1:size(B,1)
    for iDim3=1:size(B,3)
        [~,idx]=max(abs(B(iDim1,:,iDim3)));
        MAX(iDim1,iDim3)=B(iDim1,idx,iDim3);
    end %iDim3
end %iDim1
```

**Could you provide `sub2ind()` or another elegant solution for this loop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, This is what you want.
"A value of element which has maximum absolute value in a given dimension (in my case second dimension)"

Trial>> A=normrnd(0,1,[2,3,3]);

Trial>> [~,idx]=max(abs(A),[],2);

Trial>> MAX1 = A(idx)